# uuid.uuid4() collision in 1 digit

Tags: python, uuid, rfc4122

I am generating UUIDs as follows:

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().hex
```

Here are some of generated UUIDs (from different machines and different Python versions):

```
fe072a0a2a59433f9593e21bb4cc2c5f
3c1757516dfd411aad8a5d0291f92bb5
3b12a39e9d1a4cd2a43aa0c4aee41905
```

I notice that digit 4 is always in the same position within UUID.

My understanding is that UUID tokens, in accordance with [RFC4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122.html), should guarantee "uniqueness across space and time".

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: That's the UUID version. The UUID format is: `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, where `M` is the version and `N` is the variant.

Comment: @rid Sounds like a correct answer, would you like to post it?

Comment: That fixed digit does not violate "uniqueness across space and time" at all…

Comment: It's a [v**4** UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), and that's where the version bits go...